# How to Create Trigger on or Before Select in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
USE admin_gorace
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects
      WHERE name = 'trScheduler_Status_Update' AND type = 'TR')
   DROP TRIGGER trScheduler_Status_Update
GO
CREATE TRIGGER trScheduler_Status_Update
ON [Client].[Scheduler]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE , SELECT
AS
 UPDATE [Client].[Scheduler] set [Status]='Over'
 where (Convert(varchar,[Scheduler_Date],101) <=Convert(varchar,getutcdate(),101)  or Convert(varchar,[Scheduler_Date],101) <= Convert(varchar,getdate(),101))
 and (right(CONVERT( varchar, [time_to], 100),7)<= right(CONVERT( varchar, getutcdate(), 100),7) or right(CONVERT( varchar, [time_to], 100),7) <= right(CONVERT( varchar, getdate(), 100),7))
 and [Status]!='Cancelled' and [Status]!='Over'
```

GO

On `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` trigger can work But how to let it work on or before select statement

Comment: The fact that your current trigger doesn't reference either `inserted` or `deleted`, *and* the fact that you want to have it activated by `SELECT`s suggests to me that you've picked the *wrong tool* for this particular job. An SQL Server agent job may be more appropriate.

Comment: How does it even make sense to be doing comparisons on these values for both UTC *and* local time?

Comment: The accepted anwser found here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515598/anyway-to-create-a-sql-server-ddl-trigger-for-select-statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515598/anyway-to-create-a-sql-server-ddl-trigger-for-select-statements) my be a solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can not, [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189799.aspx) says:

> A trigger is a special kind of stored procedure that automatically
>   executes when an event occurs in the database server. DML triggers
>   execute when a user tries **to modify data** through a data manipulation
>   language (DML) event. DML events are INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE
>   statements on a table or view.

Answer (score 5):

There seem to be a number of issues with the way that you've set up your tables. Hopefully, you can change them. Instead of your current setup, and what you're attempting to do with a trigger, I'd have:

```
create table Scheduler (
  /* Columns - don't know what */
  EndDate datetime2 not null,
  CancelledAt datetime2 null,
  Status as CASE
    WHEN CancelledAt is not null THEN 'Cancelled'
    WHEN EndDate < getutcdate() THEN 'Over'
    ELSE 'Current' END
)
```

Now, instead of having to perform *manual* updates to the table, the `Status` column is always correct - you just have to query it. Note that I've combined `Scheduler_Date` and `time_to` into a single `datetime2` column called `EndDate` - there doesn't seem to be a good reason for splitting it into two separate columns. This also makes the comparisons simpler.

I've also chosen to just compare based on `getutcdate()` - your current code seems to be trying (somewhat badly) to cope with a mix of values that may be UTC or local dates - but won't do a decent job of that - so prevent it being an issue in the first place and only store one type of date time values in the table.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.  Not only is it not possible, even if it was it's probably not a good idea.  Tables should be the raw sources of information.  Abstraction should be in the form of views, table-valued functions, etc. to get the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Do you have any other idea regarding this topic

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?