# Capture log of fetched table rows

Tags: sql, logging, db2, fetch

I am using [db2](/questions/tagged/db2) (if you have a solution with another database, I am still interested), and am trying to identify every row that is fetched from a specific table.  The solution needs to be at the database level, because I do not have access to the actual `SELECT` statements that cause the fetch.  I would at a minimum like to capture one or more column values into a log/table for every row that is fetched from a specific table.

Here's an example:

### Table1 structure

CustNo (primary key)
CustName

### Table 1 (two rows)

12345, Joe's Crab Shack
98765, Morton's The Steakhouse

### Process

1)  Before select, log file is empty

2)  Execute:  SELECT CustName from Table1 where CustNo=12345

3)  After select, log file contains:

```
LogFile1
---------
12345
```

4)  Execute:  SELECT * from Table1

5)  After select, log file contains:

```
LogFile1
---------
12345
12345
98765
```

Thank you for any advice/recommendations....

Comment: never heard of anything to track `SELECT`. Best alternative would be to have users execute `SP` that records information that was requested. Look at this maybe you can get some helpful info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753329/how-to-create-trigger-on-or-before-select-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: ...why?  What do you need this information for?  (and which version of DB2?)  You should probably move this to DBA.se if you want some sort of configuration setting, although I can't think of anything relevant offhand.  A SP is probably your best bet - it looks like triggers only deal with updates.  Which also raises some points about your current log table: At minimum, you likely need some sort of statement counter, `occurredAt` timestamp, user credentials, etc.  Depending on the reason for the logging, you may need to save the actual row returned (or at least specific data elements)!

Comment: SaUce - I do not have access to the source of the SELECT statements, so therefore have no control over how/when the SELECTs are executed.  I thought about using an SP, but cannot come up with an approach that invokes the SP on a SELECT.

Comment: Clockwork - We are using this information for cleanup purposes -- i.e. if a row is not retrieved over a certain period, we will delete it.  The version of DB2 is AS/400 DB2 V5R4.  As mentioned, I thought about a SP, but what would trigger the SP?  I do not have access to the application source, so I have to catch the SELECT on the backend, i.e. at the database level.  Thank you for your ideas.  My example is pared down for brevity's sake - so, it is not intended to reflect all the data that we want to capture in the log.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to call a SP to log this info, you might want simply to add a *READ trigger. It's rarely a good idea to try to get some function to run whenever any record is read from a file, but a *READ trigger is possibly the most efficient way possible.

```
ADDPFTRG FILE(X) TRGTIME(*AFTER) TRGEVENT(*READ) PGM(Y)
```

Use that form of the command to add your "read-only" trigger program (Y) to a file (X). Program Y should probably do something fast like push the relevant data items onto a data queue. Then have multiple batch instances of a program that pulls entries off the queue and writes them to a log file. You really don't want a read-only trigger doing any more work than possible, and database I/O should be off the list.

Expect performance to suffer some.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the operations on the database via db2audit, but you cannot get the values used. Using the values for audit or logging will compromise sensitive data.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002072.html

Actually, if you put the ID of all read rows for a given table, it is like copying the ID column several times in the log table. At the same time, it does not give any order context, because the order in which the rows are inserted is not the same order as the rows will be stored or retrieved.

You have to rethink your logging strategy, because just inserting the 'fetched' ID is not enough. You also have to insert some context information, like who (user), when (date), from where (machine) in order to exploit that data.

Another thing you can do is to wrap the select in a stored procedure and insert the ID values in the log table, before returning the opening cursor to the caller.

Comment: You can use a logging facility for db2 in the stored procedure in order to write the values you want to log i.e. log4db2).