# SQL: Track the use of Views

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a sql database with a lot of view (2000+) - all are used ONLY for reading, never updating. Many different systems use this DB, but no one knows wich views are used. And we cannot change all the systems, that uses theese views - 
Give som good idea to track the use.. Please..

My idea was something like:
rename the view, make a SProc til insert into a trace-table and then called the original view.
And then make a new view (name like the original view) to call the SProc..
Se the sql-statements below

BUT OPENQUERY will correctly give me the result, but will NOT do the insert

Help please... :)

Here are some info on my idea

```
DB:            Cum_Test
Table          AA12345Table
View:          Cum1V
select * from  AA12345Table


First:          rename old view til Cum1V_old

Then:    New SProc
             CREATE PROCEDURE Pr_Cum1V
             AS
             BEGIN
                               SET NOCOUNT ON;
                               INSERT INTO TableTrace VALUES(GETDATE(),'Cum1V')
                               SELECT * FROM dbo.Cum1V_old;
             END            

and
CREATE VIEW Cum1v as
select * FROM OPENQUERY(LOCALSERVER,'exec Cum_Test.dbo.cPr')
```

and remember

```
 EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'LOCALSERVER',  @srvproduct = '',
 @provider = 'SQLOLEDB', @datasrc = @@servername
```

Comment: Start a trace in the profiler and then just search the executed sql for the view names

Comment: I believe [following SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515598/anyway-to-create-a-sql-server-ddl-trigger-for-select-statements) gives some answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just a draft of the solution:

1 create function that records data in text file:

```
create function record_usage (@view_name as varchar) returns int
as 
begin
    declare @cmd varchar(1000);
    select @cmd = 'echo ' + @view_name + '  >> c:\test.txt'
    exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

    return 0
end
```

2 ... and use it in your views:

```
select a,b,c,d,e,f, dbo.record_usage('Cum1V') ...
```

1. now just find a way to avoid duplicates