# Limit select size of all user queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, database-administration

Stupid question as it sounds but is there any way to implement select size limitation to specific users on SQL Server? Even though a user sends select *, the result set will contain only the first, say 10 results. Works just like the top operator but in a security context. There might be two benefits in this: 
1) Prevent adhoc queries bloating the server.
2) Limit access to sensitive data.

Thanks all.

Comment: For your second point, I don't really see how the "top 10" could be a good security. Anyway, I don't thing that's doable, without creating Views with a TOP 10 in their definition, and give access only to these views... But, I may be wrong.

Comment: You may look at row-level permissions : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669076(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Be aware that simply limiting the number of rows won't necessarily mitigate excessive resource usage.  For example "SELECT TOP (1) * FROM BillionRowTable ORDER BY NonIndexedColumn" will be very expensive even though only one row is returned.  Much depends on the particulars of the query plan.

Comment: Hi Raphael. Thank you.
Hi Dan. I didn't think of it before. Thanks for reminding.
I know it is a bit pointless but policy is policy :(
btw, I'm new around here; how do I mark your comments up as they've been helpful?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "set rowcount 10" command is kind of cool... it will limit the number of rows returned by,  a select statement to the given number.

The nice thing about it is that you can prepend it to "any" SQL statement ("set rowcount 10; select ...") and it does its thing; you don't have to tweak the select statement (which could be complex) to find where to insert "top N".

NOTE: This setting stays in effect (for the current connection) until it is turned off (with "set rowcount 0"), so you really need to manage it carefully.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create Views for your tables and do a SELECT TOP within those based on suser_sid (detailed here [Anyway to create a SQL Server DDL trigger for "SELECT" statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515598/anyway-to-create-a-sql-server-ddl-trigger-for-select-statements)).

This will prevent excessive row selection and has the benefit of being enforced against specific users, with no opportunity for them to change it.

The only time I've ever come across this is to prevent dynamic database access (outside of an application) allowing a single user to extract all the data in a database, or make excessive aggregations which would reveal sensitive operational security data; some data is more dangerous in aggregate than it is in detail.