# SQL server, 'before-select' event

Tags: sql, sql-server, events, sql-server-2016

I understand that this question was asked a million times already. I do understand how triggers work in SQL Server. But may be there're some new workarounds which I haven't found yet.
So I'm trying to understand if there any way of catching SQL server `select` statement from table/view/function event and execute some sql statement beforehand.

So far the closest way of doing this I found is - run profiler which will put all the data to table, create trigger on this table, run procedure from this trigger.
Unfortunately, even this crazy method didn't work, profiler just fails the moment the trigger tries to fire.

Are there any other crazy ideas I'm missing?

Comment: any reason why you want to do this

Comment: Also can you share more on this and elaborate what statement `execute some sql statement beforehand.`

Comment: I'd say there're various applications for this, for example logging client calls. For now I'm trying to investigate if there're a possibility to do this.

Comment: I am not sure of why you want to execute `some statement` prior to select,so i thought knowing the reason and statement can provide new ideas

Comment: if you want to log client calls, you can use extended events, it can audit select and you can log it a file for later analysis and it is very light weight.. even you can audit few tables or all the tables

Comment: I tried searching for `sp_batch_Completed`event it lead me to event notifications which i believe would serve your purpose:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-event-notification-transact-sql

Comment: While it's possible to monitor queries for select with something like 'sql_batch_starting' - I doubt you'll be able to 'pause' the running process reliably enough to preinsert the data - even if you could doesn't sound like a great idea.

Comment: On further research,event notifications can audit select and can notify you..as answered by Remus Rusanu here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517091/2975396